# jqGrid with IE8 can't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My jqGrid's grid working correctly in Firefox, Opera, IE11.
But can't work in IE8.

My jgGrid version is 4.5.4.
My jQuery version is 1.9.0

My source is as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/js/i18n/grid.locale-ja.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
```

Debbuger shows error ( at a row *3492 ).

```
3491 $t.grid.headers[lvc].width = cw;
*3492 $t.grid.headers[lvc].el.style.width=cw+"px";
3493 if(cle) { $t.grid.cols[lvc].style.width = cw+"px"; }
3494 if($t.p.footerrow) {
3495   $t.grid.footers[lvc].style.width = cw+"px";
3496 }
3497 }
```

Please teach me the method working well ?
Or never work in IE8 ?

Comment: have you gone throught the documentation?

Comment: Have you tried debug mode? Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Could you post the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem? Currently you posted **no JavaScript code** which initiate the described error. In any way I would recommend you to try the same code with the current 4.7 version of jqGrid. jqGrid 4.5.4 is more as one year old.

Comment: the error occured gridcomplete event.

Comment: at using hideCol method. I control hide or shoe colums by kind of search. I replace to jqGrid 4.7.0. but still error is occuered in IE8. anyway because IE8 user gettimg smaller, It's little problem.

Comment: $("#jbooklist").jqGrid('hideCol', columnname);   <=== error